# Multi language support for lightning components on community builder

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community-builder

We are building a lightning component to be used within community templates. 
Currently in the community builder we have the option to translate displayed labels, once we enable the language picker.
We want to provide same functionality to our ltng component, so the attributes displayed inside the "Property Editor" should have different text values depending on the selected language.
Does anyone know if it is posible to provide translation to component attributes ?

Comment: I do have the same question, did you find a solution to this (3 years later!)